Windows Go service not triggering cleanup function on stop or shutdown
I'm attempting to run a Go program as a Windows service using the github.com/golang/sys/windows/svc package, following the example provided here. Below is a simplified version of my program:
func runService(name string) {
    err := debug.Run(name, &myService{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to run service: %v", err)
    }
}

func (m *myService) Execute(args []string, r <-chan svc.ChangeRequest, changes chan<- svc.Status) (ssec bool, errno uint32) {
    const cmdsAccepted = svc.AcceptStop | svc.AcceptShutdown | svc.AcceptPauseAndContinue
    changes <- svc.Status{State: svc.StartPending}
    changes <- svc.Status{State: svc.Running, Accepts: cmdsAccepted}
    go runApp()
loop:
    for {
        select {
        case c := <-r:
            log.Printf("Received service change request: %+v", c)
            switch c.Cmd {
            case svc.Interrogate:
                changes <- c.CurrentStatus
                time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
                changes <- c.CurrentStatus
            case svc.Stop, svc.Shutdown:
                testOutput := strings.Join(args, "-")
                testOutput += fmt.Sprintf("-%d", c.Context)
                elog.Info(1, testOutput)
                signalPreviousProcess(utils.NodeExporterPidFileName)
                break loop
            case svc.Pause:
                signalPreviousProcess(utils.NodeExporterPidFileName)
                changes <- svc.Status{State: svc.Paused, Accepts: cmdsAccepted}
            case svc.Continue:
                changes <- svc.Status{State: svc.Running, Accepts: cmdsAccepted}
            default:
                elog.Error(1, fmt.Sprintf("unexpected control request #%d", c))
            }
        }
    }
    changes <- svc.Status{State: svc.StopPending}
    return
}
func main() {
    setupLogging()

    isInteractive, err := svc.IsAnInteractiveSession()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to determine if we are running in an interactive session: %v", err)
    }
    if !isInteractive {
        runService(svcName)
        return
    } else {
        log.Printf("Running in interactive mode")
        runApp()
    }
}


I've successfully created and started the service using the following commands:
sc create vcoa binPath= "\"Y:\vcoagent.exe\"
sc start vcoa

However, when I attempt to stop the service (sc stop vcoa), the signalPreviousProcess function within the Execute method (case svc.Stop, svc.Shutdown:) is not triggered. I'm unsure why this cleanup function is not being called on service stop or shutdown.
Specific questions:
1.How can I ensure that my service responds correctly to stop or shutdown commands?
2.What steps should I take to debug why the signalPreviousProcess function is not being invoked?
3.Are there any potential pitfalls or common mistakes related to handling service stop/shutdown in Go on Windows that I should be aware of?
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

…so, you've put a call to log something into the Windows EventLog (using the facilities from the package's eventlog subpackage) right at the beginning of the case c := <-r: block and have verified your service is really receiving the shutdown signal, right?

I just want to trigger signalPreviousProcess when the service stop or shutdown

«I just want to trigger…»–this is clear from the question. I asked, whether you have verified your service is for sure receiving the required signal–say, by logging the contents of c after each receive done by case c := <-r? There's no need to recite your end goal, it's pretty understandable. Unfortunately, there appears to be no straightforward answer to your question, and you need to debug. Debugging is done by partitioning the problem space into ever-decreasing pieces until the cause it reasonably localized. Here, we need to first verify the service is receiving the shutdown control.

I have debug and my service is not receive the signal (the c)

You seem to be using debug.Run to run your service; the documentation on it states: «Run executes service name by calling appropriate handler function. The process is running on console, unlike real service. Use Ctrl+C to send "Stop" command to your service.» (emphasis mine). Is this really what happens or are you trying to start your service using the appropriate Windows means? (My remark assumes you import github.com/golang/sys/windows/svc/debug to get the debug symbol in the scope).
